# Scala MapN with conditions

Tags: scala, functional-programming, applicative, scala-cats

Hi I have the following Scala code with `cats` library

```
results = patrons.map(p => {
  (verifyCardId(p.cardId), verifyAddress(p.address)).map2(
  (maybeValidCard, maybeValidAddress) => {
    val result = for {
      idCheck <- maybeValidCard
      addressCheck <- maybeValidAddress
    } yield CheckResult(p.name, idCheck, addressCheck)
  }
})
```

where `verifyCardId` and `verifyAddress` is an external API call returning a `Future` which are somehow very expensive and time consuming.

The question is how do I do the following:

- If one of the patron does not have a card, the code should be able to skip checking the card must still check patron's address
- If the patron has both then, the code should check the card and the address

How can I improve the existing code? Thanks heaps

Edit:
Add more information about the preference to skip one of the expensive API calls

Answer (score 1):

- If result of address verification doesn't depend on result of card verification then untie them (`flatMap` binds monads).
- Model `CheckResult` should be adjusted to case of missing card.

**extended sample**

```
    case class Patron(name: String, cardId: String, address: String)
    case class CheckResult(name: String, idCheck: Option[Boolean], addressCheck: Boolean)
    def verifyCardId(cardId: String) = Future{
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      Some(true)
    }
    def verifyAddress(address: String) = Future{
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      Some(true)
    }

    val patrons = List(Patron("p_name", "1234", "Somewhere St. 42"))

    val start = LocalDateTime.now()
    val results = patrons.map(p => {
      (verifyCardId(p.cardId), verifyAddress(p.address)).map2(
        (maybeValidCard, maybeValidAddress) => {
          for {
            addressCheck <- maybeValidAddress
          } yield CheckResult(p.name, maybeValidCard, addressCheck)
        })
    })
    val headResult = Await.result(results.head, Duration.Inf)
    val end = LocalDateTime.now()
    val duration = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start, end)
```

**short output**

```
    patrons: List[Patron] = List(Patron(p_name,1234,Somewhere St. 42))
    headResult: Option[CheckResult] = Some(CheckResult(p_name,Some(true),true))
    duration: Long = 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I guess I didn't explain my intention well enough. I have updated the question. True that both verifications do not depends on each other. But it is also preferred if they both can be called at the same time to save time. My intention is to skip one of them given a specific scenario (i.e. no card)

Comment: I updated answer. Only results of calls are untied. Futures are computed asynchronous and in parallel way.